# ngRoute preventing view from seeing controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently working on an application and the view can't find the controller for some reasons. I suspect it's because of the ngRoute in the app.js. This is the error I'm getting: Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function.
Below is a snippet of the code.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
<script src="select.controller.js"></script>
<div>
<label>Pick a title:
<select ng-model="data. title">
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
</select>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>Type your name:
<input type="text" ng-model="data.test">
</label>
</div>
<input type="submit" ng-click="info()">
</div>
```

JS 
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.data = {
title: "Mr",
test: ""
}

$scope.info = function()
{
alert("you are " + $scope.data.title + " " + $scope.data.test)
console.log('T');

}

});
```

App.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
.config(config)
.run(run);
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
controller: 'HomeController',
templateUrl: 'home.view.html',
controllerAs: 'vm',
})

.when('/select', {
controller: 'SelectController',
templateUrl: 'select.html',
controllerAs: 'vm',

.when('/login', {
controller: 'LoginController',
templateUrl: 'login.view.html',
controllerAs: 'vm'
})

.when('/register', {
controller: 'RegisterController',
templateUrl: 'register.view.html',
controllerAs: 'vm'
});
}
run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];
function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
// keep user logged in after page refresh
$rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' +        $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
}
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next,  current) {

var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
$location.path('/login');
           }
 });
 }
```

})();

Comment: you have multiple issues here.  firstly, you can't load a script for the controller from inside the partial view.  secondly, you are **re-declaring** your app in that file, so even if that file loaded, it would break your app.  (i.e. use `var app = angular.module('app');` instead of `var app = angular.module('app', []);`.  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#setting-vs-getting.

Comment: also, don't use `ng-controller` in the template and `controller` in the route at the same time.